# Creating an image in Docker from a .tar file and what are the true differences in build/import/load

Tags: docker, load, tar

I understand that there was a question almost identical, but I don't have the reputation to comment, and none of the responses seemed to help me. I have my .tar file, let's say it's name is 'qwertyapp.tar' and it is in my working directory <>

I have tried:

```
docker build /qwertyapp.tar
docker build qwertyapp.tar
docker import qwertyapp.tar
docker load -i qwertyapp.tar
```

Along with several other small modifications with no luck.

Mostly I am seeing this as the return:

```
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
```

OR

```
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
```

Sorry if this is somewhat of a repeat question, but I can not seem to figure it out. Spent over a day Googling and using Docker Documentation.

Comment: Do you actually have a tar file?  For example, can `tar tf qwertyapp.tar` successfully list its contents?

Comment: I mean, I know that the file extension is .tar. But when I type your code with the name of my file, I get this response:
'''tar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.''
But I can double click on the .tar file in my file explorer and yes, there are contents inside.
There is one folder named a ton of letter and numbers randomly if this means anything to you, then when I double click that folder, I have a File titled json, a WinZip file with a .tar extension, and a File titled VERSION.

Hope this helps!